# What does it mean? Is this might be Issue in OS configuration?

Tags: linux

It said:

> segfault at 10 ip 00000000005da860 sp 00007f7a155ed9e0 error 4 in gateway [400000+1213000]

What does it mean?

Might this be an issue in the OS configuration?

[Picture of the display with the error, below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fljth.png):

[image: picture of a display with an error]

Answer (score 0):

This mean that the process `gateway` is generating a segmentation fault.

First and foremost, it's a bug, a programming error. 
Nevertheless, it may be caused by a bad configuration.

Let's says that:

- the `gateway` program needs a `address` parameter.
- this parameter is missing in your configuration file.

If developer didn't checked that `address` parameter has been supplied before using it, then it may lead to a segmentation fault.